# How can I get plant Genome size, total number of genes, EST, and chromosomes number

Tags: public-databases

How can I get plant Genome size, total number of genes, EST and chromosome number from phytozom and plantDB?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the URLs from the image you pasted? The genome size should be trivial to calculate if you download the files. Also, please add the source of the image you are showing.

Comment: Both resources do not offer a well documented "programmatical" access option - either REST or something equivalent, so I believe it is not possible to (trivially) do it with Python or R.

Comment: It looks like you've got to download the files. A user defined script can do all the stuff you want.

Answer (score 2):

Ensembl plants has a REST API, you might be able to get all these details (except possibly EST numbers) there: http://ensemblgenomes.org/info/access/rest

For example this query gives you the Arabidopsis genome size: http://rest.ensemblgenomes.org/info/genomes/arabidopsis_thaliana?content-type=application/json